# jsPlumb not working after loading jQuery EasyUI (conflict between jQueryUI and EasyUI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb, jquery-easyui

I come to a real problem with jsPlumb and jQuery EasyUI.

Here what happens. I've got a website which is using EasyUI, I was trying to add some jsPlumb connections to it and this connections are not behaving as I want them to do.

I prepare some demo with jsPlumb only and it's working. But when I add it to existing site connections are not working.

After investigating where is the conflict I came to this:

jsPlumb is working as long as I don't load EasyUI. After loading EasyUI:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

- I cannot create new connections by dragging source Endpoint (I drag endpoint but now new connection is created)
- Endpoints don't follow div they belong to (they position themselves right when you point them by mouse)

I prepare 2 demos using jsFiddle to show what I mean. The ONLY think that differs this two samles is external resource of jquery.easyui

- Working jsPlumb [Full Screen Result](http://jsfiddle.net/matbochynski/t39jz/embedded/result/)
- Not Working: [Full Screen Result](http://jsfiddle.net/matbochynski/6BTCJ/2/embedded/result/)

How I can solve this? Maybe some of You know where is  conflict. My site is to advaced to change EasyUI to anything else at this point, and I really want to use jsPlumb as I cannot find any as powerful toolkit as this.

---

EDIT:

As was suggested I've tried to override draggable and it partially works but not as I want it to.

```
(function($){
    var __old_draggable = $.fn.draggable;
    $.fn.draggable = function(){
        if(this.hasClass('_jsPlumb_endpoint') || this.hasClass('window')){
            return;
        }
        return __old_draggable.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    $.extend($.fn.draggable,__old_draggable);
})(jQuery);
```

Partially because:

- Endpoints are no longer draggable - that's good,
- But they do NOT create new connection, that's bad.
- They do NOT follow window they are attached to.

Furthermore now I now, that EasyUI override jQuery draggable and this cause this strange (for me) behaviour. Sadly, I have problems with force draggable method to be original jQuery method... So I'm looking forward to other solutions for my problem

---

Edit: I delete everything connected with draggable and dropable override in EasyUI and its working. Now the problem is how to do this in program not in easyui script, as somebody will update to new version and everything will stop working...

Comment: Try changing the order of the files, put jsPlumb after EasyUI.

Comment: sadly, No difference at all... Tried all possibilities

Comment: There is a fork of jsPlumb dealing with EasyUI. Maybe that helps? https://github.com/KodingSykosis/jsPlumb/commits/master

Comment: WOW! That's awesome. I see in code that it uses EasyUI but there is no info in README or somewhere else... 

koppor, this should be an answer, not only comment

Comment: OK, I put it as separate answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here is the best working solution for me.

What happened here is that EasyUI draggable, dropable methods overrides jQueryUI methods. jsPlumb is designed to work with jQueryUI and not with EasyUI as it turned out.

I've found that EasyUI framework provide method [easyloader](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/easyloader.php) which allow you to choose which modules to load! GREAT! I have to change my code a little removing everything connected with EasyUI from **`*.html`** documents (as no EasyUI modules are known on creating DOM).

In HTML document place

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.2/easyloader.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.2/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

then in your javascript I've done something like this:

```
$(function () {
    using(['panel', 'datetimebox', 'tabs', 
            'accordion', 'layout', 'linkbutton',
            'datagrid'], function(){
        initAll.call(this);
    });
});
```

where **`using`** is an [easyloader](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/easyloader.php) function which load modules. **`initAll`** is my function where all initialization of EasyUI components are for example:

```
var initAll = function () {
    //initialize all html elements which uses EasyUI
    $('#layout').layout({fit:true});
    $('#tabscontainer').tabs({fit:true, border:false});
    $('#accordion').accordion({fit: true, border:false});
}
```

The only thing you MUST be aware of is that you CANNOT use modules which are dependant of draggable/droppable modules to have jsPlumb working. Dependencies can be found in easyloader.js source code. For EasyUI version 1.3.2 they are: *slider, tree, window, combotree, dialog, messager*.

Comment: rats, I need to use easyui-tree and jsplumb :-/

Comment: in the end I dropped easyui and went for another lib

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of jsPlumb dealing with EasyUI. Maybe that helps? http://github.com/KodingSykosis/jsPlumb/commits/master

Demo sources are available at https://github.com/KodingSykosis/jsPlumb/tree/master/demo/jeasyui

Comment: Why it doesn't work for you? Still conflicts in draggable and droppable?

Comment: yes I was still getting errors on initialisation, in the end I dropped easyui and went for another lib

Answer (score 0):

Override EasyUI `$.fn.draggable`. Try detecting jsPlumb classes on `this` and prevent from manipulating jsPlumb nodes.

Something like `if(....hasClass('jsPlumbClass') ) return;`

might help. The libraries are in conflict somehow, sorry about that.

Comment: I edited the question and added what I've tried, and reason why this is not working for me.